# Creating an automatic page size inQGIS Print-Layout with a pre-defined scale

Tags: qgis, print-composer

How can QGIS Print-Layout with a given scale (eg 1:50000) create an automatic page size and layout equal to the coverage of the selected map layers?

I tried it in the page properties, it didn't help:

```
bounds_width(@geometry)/50
bounds_height(@geometry)/50
```

and

```
bounds_width (@map_extent )/50
bounds_height (@map_extent )/50
```

and

```
@map_extent_width/50
@map_extent_height/50
```

:( need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `layer_property` expression for that:

page_width: `bounds_width(layer_property('layername','extent'))/50`

to get the maximum extend from all layers you can use:
`array_max(array_foreach(@layers, bounds_width(layer_property(@element,'extent'))/50))`

To get the extend from only seleced layers is IMO not possible....

Comment: Thank you! This works with one layer. How to apply to multiple selected layers?

Comment: I've edited my solution, but to get the extend from only seleced layers is IMO not possible....